# How can I make a down movement at the last line go to the end of the line?

Tags: cursor-movement

In some editors, if you press <kbd>↓</kbd> while in the middle of the last line, it takes you to the end of the line (or, equivalently, the document). I have grown somewhat used to this. How do I obtain the same behaviour in Vim?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to do what you want:

```
:noremap <expr> <Down> line('.') == line('$') ? '$' : 'j'
```

- We use the `<expr>` keyword to tell Vim to expect an expression, and use the value of that.
- `line('.')` gets the current line number, `line('$')` gets the last line number

For insert mode, you can use a slightly different version:

```
:inoremap <expr> <Down> line('.') == line('$') ? '<End>' : '<Down>'
```

This uses `<End>` and `<Down>`, rather than `$` and `j` (actually, those will work in `noremap` as well).

Comment: Dammit I forgot to mention that I'd like it for insert mode too. I suppose that can be handled by an `imap` with `<ESC>` prepended and `a` appended?

Comment: @muru I would say that using `<Down>` and `<End>` is easier ;-) See updated answer.

Comment: (mumble mumble) tunnel vision (mumble mumble). :D

Comment: Whitespace is totally valid in the right-hand-side of an `<expr>` mapping. You might be thinking of `:set`?

Comment: @tommcdo Yeah, I had it mixed up :-/